# How can I darken a stained finish without sanding/stripping?

Tags: finishing, technique, staining

My current maple cabinets have a brown stained finish and I would like to darken the stain a bit more. What can I do to accomplish this WITHOUT needing to sand everything down and start from scratch? Preferably something that I can just brush/wipe on.

Comment: This should be easily doable, there are numerous types of coloured finish available. Have you used "gel stain" before? That's likely your easiest option, although if you'd like to try toning lacquer that might work well for you depending on the size and number of cabinets you have to do (suspect it will work out more expensive too since you'll be buying it in rattle cans).

Comment: If the cabinets have any sort of a sealing finish over the stain, that may need to be _carefully_ sanded off prior to adding additional stain. Some of the ones I've seen would just cause any liquid (including additional stain) to bead on the surface.